# How to query custom post type by two terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am having issues when it comes to displaying a post based off two taxonomy selections. As of right now I am able to display my post based of one tax selection which is speakeryear. The problem is when I want to add my second tax which is placement_category and narrow it down based on its slug selection I am still displaying all my tax based off speaker year.

```
 <?php $args = array('showposts'=>25,'post_type'=>'test', 'taxonomy' => 'placement_category','field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'test1', 'speakeryear' =>$options[year] );$query = new WP_Query($args);while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>   
  <article class="card-half">
       Test
  </article>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here I am calling the post based off its tax selection, which only displays speakeryear tax.

```
 'taxonomy' => 'placement_category','field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'test1',
```

I added the above tax to the query in hopes to narrow down my post visibility, but had no luck.

This is what I am trying to achieve display all post from tax speakeryear then all the post that are displayed from speakeryear I want it be narrowed down to placement_category based on its slug selection.

I am displaying placement_category slugs test1 and test2 in two different locations on my website. All tax names and slugs are correct on my site. What am I doing wrong in narrowing down my post?

UPDATED:

It is now working with the updated code

```
 <?php $args = array('showposts'=>25,'post_type'=>'liaisons', 'speakeryear' =>$options[year] );$query = new WP_Query($args);while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
      if( has_term( 'test1', 'placementcategory' ) ) {
 ?> 
 <article class="card-half">
       Test
  </article>
<?php } endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: figured it out I removed the taxonomy code within my query and added if( has_term( 'test', 'placementcategory' ) ) {

Comment: @DaveRomseyjust did it thank you. I just can't accept my answer until two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out I removed the taxonomy code within my query and added

```
  <?php $args = array(
               'showposts'=>25,
               'post_type'=>'liaisons',
               'speakeryear' =>$options[year] 
        );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
            $query->the_post();
         if( has_term( 'test1', 'placementcategory' ) ) { ?> 
           <article class="card-half">Test</article>
   <?php }
    endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Glad you managed to work this out yourself +1 for that, but you might want to change the showposts to posts_per_page. Although showposts still functions with backward compatibility, the codex is showing showposts s depreciated and could come out anytime. thus breaking your code